# Reasoning doesn't give same results with *

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, rdfs, linked-data

I am enabling Forward chaining like this:

```
static final String inputData = "http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~pms509/past_projects/2014-2015/hw1/kallikratis.n3";
MemoryStore store = new MemoryStore();
Repository repo = new SailRepository(new ForwardChainingRDFSInferencer(store));
System.out.println("Forward chaining enabled");
repo.initialize();

//Store file
File file = new File(inputData);
String fileBaseURI = "http://www.semanticweb.org/owl/owlapi/turtle";
RDFFormat fileRDFFormat = RDFFormat.N3;

RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection();
con.add(file, fileBaseURI, fileRDFFormat);
...
```

and then I query like this:

```
"SELECT ?class "                                +
"WHERE {"                                       +
        "?rsrc geo:has_name \"foo\" . "         +
        "?rsrc geo:belongs_to ?a ."             +
"}";
```

However this will ***not*** give me same results as with `geo:belongs_to*`. I will get only the direct `belongs_to` linkage, not the inferred ones, as I would expect!

I want to get same results however, why I am not?

Comment: What 'inferred ones' are you talking about? Why would you expect that the RDFS reasoner infers _any_ `belongsTo` relations?

Comment: Because that's what I thought. I thought that the reasoner would add a `belongs_to` linkage from Municipality to Country. I am mistaken @JeenBroekstra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RDFS inferencer *only* does, well, RDFS inferencing - that is, it reasons using the rules defined in the [RDF Semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/). These rules *only* cover relatively basic things such as subclass/type inheritance, and domain/range inference. So for example, if your data has a class `Car` and it defines `Car` as a subclass of `Vehicle`, then the RDFS inferencer will infer that any instance of the class `Car` is *also* an instance of `Vehicle`.

But this kind of inheritance *only* works for these specific relations (subclass, type, subpropertyof). It does not automatically infer in the general case, that if `X someProperty Y` and `Y someProperty Z`, that it then follows that `X someProperty Z`.

If you want that kind of reasoning support, you either need a custom rule reasoner (Sesame has some limited support for this, with improved support in the form of [SPIN rules](http://spinrdf.org) coming out soon), or you need to move to the next level of expressivity in ontology languages, which is OWL (in which case, a Sesame-compatible OWL reasoner like Ontotext GraphDB or Stardog is needed). Or alternatively, just solve it at query time (for example by using a transitive property path).